# Producing a sequence of a list elements product

Tags: python, list, sympy

Using `sympy`, let's say a list:

```
xs=[-2,-1,1,2]
```

And I need to get:

```
[(x-x_0),(x-x_0)*(x-x_1),(x-x_0)*(x-x_1)*(x-x_2),...(x-x_0)*(x-x_1)*(x-x_2)...*(x-x_n)]
```

For my list `xs`, that would be:

```
[(x+2),(x+2)*(x+1),(x+2)*(x+1)*(x-1),(x+2)*(x+1)*(x-1)*(x-2)]
```

I've tried:

```
terminos = []
def lag_l(xx):
    x = Symbol("x")
    for x_i in xx:
        x__i = ((x-x_i) * prod(t) for t in terminos)
        terminos.append((x-x_i))
    print terminos[::-1]
```

And so:

```
lag_l([-2,-1,1,2])
```

But that's only printing the same back. What have I got wrong?

Comment: x__i (two underscores) is not used anywhere in the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def product_sequence(xs):
  x = Symbol('x')
  y = 1
  res = []
  for item in xs:
     y *= x - item
     res.append(y) 
  return res
```

Or, more elegant using `yield`:

```
def product_gen(xs):
  x = Symbol('x')
  y = 1
  for item in xs:
     y *= x - item
     yield y

res = list(product_gen(xs))
```

Comment: Great, when it comes to computational cost, which is it better?

Comment: I'd imagine using a generator would be faster, because it creates the list in one go instead of calling `append` repeatingly (especially for long lists), but why don't try and see?

Comment: I'll check out. Even it's sptupid, is there any way the terms remain in the *original* order?

For example, for second element obtaining `(x + 2)*(x + 1)`  instead of `(x + 1)*(x + 2)`

Comment: It outputs:  `x + 2, (x + 1)*(x + 2), x*(x + 1)*(x + 2), x*(x - 1)*(x + 1)*(x + 2), x*(x - 2)*(x - 1)*(x + 1)*(x + 2)]`

Comment: I believe this is the way `sympy` automatically orders the elements. I'm not aware of a way to control this automatic ordering

Comment: Actually, there's a `sympy.sstr` function, which takes an `order` option. However, the docs say the `order` arg "does nothing for Mul objects"...